# How to use jquery to create a "navigation" to hide and show content on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

***Desired situation***: All the quiz content is hidden from the start and I have a ul list with li items as my "quiz questions navigations" which is supposed to show 1 quiz question (with the radio btns choices and the div resp) at a time when the "questions navigation is clicked.

***Current situation***: I was thinking of having an array to check for the same attr name "qns1", but I am not familiar with JavaScript syntax

**Javascript**

```
$(".span9").hide();
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="quiznav">
     <li>Q1</li><br>
     <li>Q2</li><br>
     <li>Q3</li><br>
</ul>

<div class="span9">

        <div class="qnstitle" name="qns1">Q1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns1" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="A">a) asdf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris aliquet ligula mi. Aenean eu magna quam. In ultrices nisi non tellus molestie ut mattis turpis convallis. </p>
        </div>

        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns1" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="B">b) bsdf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns1">
            <p>Proin porta, ante eu feugiat facilisis, nulla erat porta dui, sed pellentesque orci sapien quis libero. Nam nec nibh metus, nec luctus massa.</p>
        </div>

        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns1" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="C">c) csdf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns1">
            <p>Donec metus nibh, pharetra vitae semper id, blandit non lorem. Fusce ut metus a dui egestas congue quis quis augue. Suspendisse sed nunc sed nulla volutpat pharetra at vel purus.</p>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="qnstitle" name="qns2">Q2. Nunc sed aliquet enim.</div>
        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns2" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="A">a) azzzddsaf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns2">
            <p>Donec metus nibh, pharetra vitae semper id, blandit non lorem.</p>
        </div>

        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns2" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="B">b) bzzzzddafdsf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns2">
            <p>Aenean eu metus id dui tristique aliquam. Pellentesque non scelerisque nisi. Integer a nibh orci</p>
        </div>

        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns2" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="C">c) czzdfasdf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns2">
            <p>Pellentesque turpis libero, consectetur nec dictum eu, accumsan a sapien. Integer eget ultrices risus. Pellentesque vel orci purus.</p>
        </div>

<div class="qnstitle" name="qns3">Q3. Nunc sed aliquet enim.</div>
        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns3" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="A">a) azzzddsaf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns3">
            <p>Donec metus nibh, pharetra vitae semper id, blandit non lorem.</p>
        </div>

        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns3" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="B">b) bzzzzddafdsf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns3">
            <p>Aenean eu metus id dui tristique aliquam. Pellentesque non scelerisque nisi. Integer a nibh orci</p>
        </div>

        <label class="radio">
            <input name="qns3" class="radioBtn" type="radio" value="C">c) czzdfasdf
        </label>
        <div class="resp" data-qns="qns3">
            <p>Pellentesque turpis libero, consectetur nec dictum eu, accumsan a sapien. Integer eget ultrices risus. Pellentesque vel orci purus.</p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of span9 -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes wrapping each question in a `div` is necessary. This may be the effect you are looking for, fading out of current and fading in the new question based on click event of the navigation. The API `.delay()` was used to ease transition of the question.

```
$(".btn").click(function(){    
    $('.qns').fadeOut();
    $('#qns' + $(this).html()).delay(450).fadeIn(); 
});
```

See example here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bsXwn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should first wrap your each question in `div` then you can use jQuery `toggle()` to show and hide the question based on click event of the question navigation.

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $("#" + $(this).text()).toggle("fast");
});​
```

See example here **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/E46BH/)**.

Comment: Your method works for showing 1 question after another. What I hope to achieve is for 1 question to be shown while the rest is hidden each time I click on a different question navigation.